# Phonegap Android write to sd card

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

Given code below if i test with Phonegap Developer in mobile, it creates a file in root of my Nexus 5 device.

```
// create a file writer object
function CreateFileWriter()
{
    // request the file system object
window.requestFileSystem( LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, OnFileSystemSuccess,fail);
}

function OnFileSystemSuccess( pFileSystemObj )
{
    console.log( pFileSystemObj.name );
    console.log( pFileSystemObj.root.name );

    pFileSystemObj.root.getFile( "file_name.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, OnFileGetSuccess, fail);
}

function OnFileGetSuccess( pFileEntryObj )
{
    pFileEntryObj.createWriter( function(pWriterObj){ 
    gWriterObj  = pWriterObj; 
    }, fail );
}

function fail(evt)
{
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

But, if I deploy the app and generate the apk. After installation in my device. The file is not created in root.

I have given permission in AndroidManifest.xml and added file plugin. Also, debugged from gapdebug. It does not shows any error. I assume the file is created somewhere else. but I need to write file on root of sdcard or internal memory.

Please Help!

Thanks,

Comment: I think you should avoid using the HTML5 API, use the [Cordova File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) which works very well

Comment: I am using **Cordova File Plugin** not the HTML5 API

Comment: Ok but resolve line should be something like: `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( cordova.file.dataDirectory + "myfile.dat", onSuccess, onError );` - another point: are you calling it in the _deviceready_ event ?

Comment: yes that deviceready event is being called. after that the button shows up. and i have called this in that button. Request you to show an example if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write file example:

```
var fileName = 'myfile.txt';    // your file name
var data = '...';               // your data, could be useful JSON.stringify to convert an object to JSON string
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function( directoryEntry ) {
    directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function( fileEntry ) {
        fileEntry.createWriter( function( fileWriter ) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function( result ) {
                console.log( 'done.' );
            };
            fileWriter.onerror = function( error ) {
                console.log( error );
            };
            fileWriter.write( data );
        }, function( error ) { console.log( error ); } );
    }, function( error ) { console.log( error ); } );
}, function( error ) { console.log( error ); } );
```

Comment: Mat you are great. I have looking for this since a week. Thanks again :)